# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have 2 dimensions. But I specified dense_3 to have 1 dimension

Tags: python, keras, scnnode

I keep getting this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 10, 1)
```

but I specified dense_3 to have 1 dimension, here's my code:

```
X_train=X_train.reshape(1,10,200,200)
y_train=y_train.reshape(1,10,1)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(10,200,200)))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
          optimizer='adam',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, 
      batch_size=3, epochs=100, verbose=1)
```

Even if I change the Y data to 2 dimensions, it doesn't work and I get:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 10, 2)
```

The thing that I mostly don't understand, is that in another project, I did the same thing and it worked.

Comment: can you explain your train data dimensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see `model.summary()`, which except the shape of output is `(?,1)`. But your shape of `y_train` is `(1,10,1)`.

So either you adjust `y_train` to `(?,1)` or you adjust the model to match your inputs depending on your need.

```
print(model.summary())
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 8, 198, 32)        57632     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 6, 196, 32)        9248      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 3, 98, 32)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 3, 98, 32)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 9408)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 128)               1204352   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 64)                8256      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 65        
=================================================================
Total params: 1,279,553
Trainable params: 1,279,553
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

**Edit**

You should change `Flatten()` layer and model structure if you except 2 dimensions. Because I don't know what network structure you need, I can't correct it for you. Of course, you can also keep `y_train` is `(1,10,1)`.Trying to follow it.

```
model.add(Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Reshape((10,1)))
```

I recommend that you modify `y_train` under the original structure.You can completely change `y_train` to `(?,10)`.

```
# shape=(?,10)
y_train=y_train.reshape(1,10)
# change shape
model.add(Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Comment: but how can it expect 2 dimensions if the summary shows 1?

Comment: @Emilio I added it to the answer.